# Invalid URI supplied error when trying to clone a site to localhost

Tags: error

I'm trying to clone a copy of a production site to run on MAMP. I've downloaded all the site's files (a whopping 4+GB) and took a copy of the database. I ran a searhc and replace on the production URL to use the localhost URL e.g 127.0.0.1/magento (no underscores in it).

I updated the local.xml to use the local copy of the database.

I'm nowhere near a Magento expert but offered to install a new theme with some small CSS updates for a friend so any help would be very much appreciated as I wasn't planning on spending hours getting a clone of the site to work.

One thing I did notice, and the link doens't work, is that the link to the error report has the port listed in it twice for some reason http://127.0.0.1:8888:8888/magento/errors/report.php?id=489737565032&skin=default

Answer (score 1):

Figure it out! I just needed to clear the cache folders. Found the solution in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oUU9t2RGqMg